# Selecting a single column from model to controller in codeigniter3.0.0

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter.
I need only the available column from the model than what code I write in the controller to get a single column

My model code is:

```
public function  check_reservation($restaurant_id,$date,$people,$start_time,$end_time){    
    $sql="SELECT
    r.restaurant_id,r.restaurant_name,r.capacity,rs.start_time,rs.end_time,rs.people,rs.date,r.capacity - SUM(IFNULL(rs.people,0)) AS available FROM restaurant r
    LEFT JOIN reservation rs ON r.restaurant_id = rs.restaurant_id
    AND ".$date." = rs.`date`
    AND ".$people." = rs.`people`
    AND '".$start_time."' = rs.`start_time`
    AND '".$end_time."' = rs.`end_time`
    WHERE r.restaurant_id = ".$restaurant_id."
    GROUP BY r.`restaurant_id`";

    $query=$this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you need. If you want to get only one column in the Controller, when you iterate with foreach (or for), you ask for your column name.

```
foreach ( $records as $record ) {
    echo $record['restaurant_name'];
    echo "<br/>";
}
```